# Nginx error_page and possible PHP redirect not working

Tags: http, redirect, nginx, php

In my nginx default conf file I have:

```
error_page 404 /?p=error&c=404&r=3;
```

This loads index.php and runs through a bunch of code, possible resulting in PHP wanting to redirect to where it found the file.  The issue is I can't make it redirect.  The code below returns a blank white page, with the HTTP headers having the correct Location Header but the status still says 404 which is presumably why Firefox isn't redirecting.

```
header('HTTP/1.0 302 Found'); header("Location: ".$root.'/'.$url); die();
```

Any help on how to fix this would be great, thanks!

Also if it helps this server is running Ubuntu, Nginx and PHP-FPM

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by changing

```
error_page 404 /?p=error&c=404&r=3;
```

to

```
error_page 404 = /?p=error&c=404&r=3;
```